# Kibana is not running on FreeBSD

Tags: service, kibana, daemon, elastic-stack, freebsd

I'm fighting with `kibana` since few days and I don't overcome to start it on my FreeBSD server.

This is my environment:

- FreeBSD 11.1-STABLE
- ElasticSearch 5.3.0
- Kibana 5.3.0
- Logstash 5.*.*

ElasticSearch and Logstash work fine. But I don't overcome to start kibana service.

This is files according to kibana:

**kibana.yml file:**

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are 
both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "0.0.0.0"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy. This only affects
# the URLs generated by Kibana, your proxy is expected to remove the basePath value before forwarding requests
# to Kibana. This setting cannot end in a slash.
server.basePath: "/qual/kibana"

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# The URL of the Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"

# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "discover"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "user"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files validate that your Elasticsearch backend uses the same key files.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 0

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana.log

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# The default locale. This locale can be used in certain circumstances to substitute any missing
# translations.
#i18n.defaultLocale: "en"
```

**/usr/local/etc/rc.d/kibana:**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# $FreeBSD: head/textproc/kibana5/files/kibana.in 462830 2018-02-24 14:17:41Z feld $
#

# PROVIDE: kibana
# REQUIRE: DAEMON
# KEYWORD: shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name=kibana
rcvar=kibana_enable

load_rc_config $name

: ${kibana_enable:="NO"}
: ${kibana_config:="/usr/local/etc/kibana.yml"}
: ${kibana_user:="www"}
: ${kibana_group:="www"}
: ${kibana_log:="/var/log/kibana.log"}

required_files="${kibana_config}"
pidfile="/var/run/${name}/${name}.pid"
start_precmd="kibana_precmd"
procname="/usr/local/bin/node"
command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
command_args="-f -p ${pidfile} env BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 ${procname} /usr/local/www/kibana5/src/cli serve --config ${kibana_config} --log-file ${kibana_log}"

kibana_precmd()
{
    if [ ! -d $(dirname ${pidfile}) ]; then
        install -d -o ${kibana_user} -g ${kibana_group} $(dirname ${pidfile})
    fi

    if [ ! -f ${kibana_log} ]; then
        install -o ${kibana_user} -g ${kibana_group} -m 640 /dev/null ${kibana_log}
    fi

    if [ ! -d /usr/local/www/kibana5/optimize ]; then
        install -d -o ${kibana_user} -g ${kibana_group} /usr/local/www/kibana5/optimize
    fi
}

run_rc_command "$1"
```

**/etc/rc.conf:**

`kibana_enable="YES"`

But when I execute: `service kibana start`
I get:

```
root@server:/var/log # service kibana start
Starting kibana.
root@server:/var/log # service kibana status
kibana is not running.
```

I don't know why ?

Comment: Check `/var/log/kibana.log` also probably you may want to install elk/kibana 6.5.4 they are already available in the ports

Comment: My `kibana.log` file is empty. I assume there is an issue with node. I have node6, but if I try to install node8 or node12, it uninstalls kibana5. I need to keep elasticsearch5 so I can't install kibana 6 right ?

Comment: Try to run kibana directly and check the stdout, regarding the versions yes, they need to be the same.

Comment: @nbari How it will be possible to install something like this : `pkg install kibana-5.3.0` ? I have this issue `pkg: No packages available to install matching 'kibana-5.3.0' have been found in the repositories`

Comment: If need a specific version probably is easy if you install it from source, to know more about pkg visit https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the service in debug mode
   `sh -x /usr/local/etc/rc.d/kibana start`
2. find which command is used to start the kibana service. For kibana, the command should be something like `/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/www/kibana6/src/cli serve --config /usr/local/etc/kibana/kibana.yml`
3. Start the process in foreground

It is possible that `node` is not properly installed or some permission issue.